# Hi, can anyone tell me code how to create histogram without the toolbox (imhist,hist) from matlab?

Tags: matlab, histogram, toolbox

can anyone tell me how to create histogram from an grayscale image without the function from the matlab.

Thanks

Comment: ...and you have tried ?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service, nor a free debugging service. We help *you* write good code. What that means is you need to make an attempt, show us the code and ask a specific question about that code that will help you progress it. Please read [how and what kind of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can ask here, and how to write a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You don't need a toolbox to make a histogram

Comment: [m n]=size(F);
x=0;
H=0;
for z=1:256
 
    for i=1:m
        for j=1:n
               
            x==F(i,j);
            H(x+1)=H(x+1)+1
            
        end
    end  
H;
end 


bar(H)

Comment: i try that way.. and got nothing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more efficient than your code:

```
histogram = zeros(1,256);
for value = 1:256 % loop through possible values
    histogram(value) = histogram(value) + length(find(F(:)==value));
end
```

Note that this code makes a histogram for values from 1 to 256. For grayscale images you might need one from 0 to 255. But I'll let you change this on your own for matters of practice.

**edit**: 
Since you asked for a revision of your code, let me comment on it:

```
 [m n]=size(F);
 x=0;
```

No need to set `x` to zero, you are overwriting it later.

```
 H=0;
```

Instead of setting `H` to zero you should initialize it as an array, since you want to fill `H(x)` later. Something like `H = zeros(1,256);`

```
for z=1:256
```

I'm not sure what this loop over z is supposed to do. You never use `z`. You can remove it.

```
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n       
        x==F(i,j);
```

As I said below, this should be `x=F(i,j);` instead, as `==` is a test for equality.

```
        H(x+1)=H(x+1)+1
```

This works if all values in `F` are guaranteed to be between 0 and 255. Though I would say it's not very good style.

Also, put a semicolon at the end of this line to suppress the outputs, otherwise your command line gets flooded (which is also slowing down things a lot).

```
    end
end
H;
```

The last line does nothing. Why is it there?

```
end
```

The outer loop over z is not needed (see above).

So, here is a "sanitized" version of your code:

```
[m,n] = size(F);
H = zeros(1,256);
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        x=F(i,j);
        H(x+1)=H(x+1)+1;
    end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so efficient, it works, but can it written with the long way like my code up there?

Comment: so that the coding sequence can be seen in detail, and making it easier to create the flow charts diagram.

Comment: I commented on and cleaned up your code. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, thank you very much..that much helps @florian, i'll try to add the code to another code in my GUI.. thank a lot.. :)